# Cannot get focus on new opened tab with selenium IDE

Tags: get, window, new-operator, selenium-ide

I'm trying to create some web test with selenium IDE. But I have one problem when I click on a javascript link it opened a new tab. I need perform some check on this new tab but I can't get he focus that is still in main page. I tried several things that I'ad search on google without succeed to do it works. I hope that someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

#### Update:

So I tried several things and I tink I'm on a good way.

I can get windows names with :

StoreAllWindowNames names
echo names=${name}

I have something like:
  , 987dfg4545sdfgsd

It seems that value before "," is the NULL so the default page and the other value is the name of my page.

But I'm not able to open it with a selectWindow.

Does someone know how should I do it ??

Thanks in advance.

More info about my selenium tests:

```
<tr>
    <td>setSpeed</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Show Tree...</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>storeAllWindowNames</td>
    <td>names</td>
    <td>array</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${names}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPopUp</td>
    <td>${names}</td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>name=${names}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Search</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Results:

```
* [info] Executing: |setSpeed | 1000 | |
* [info] Executing: |selectWindow | null | |
* [info] Executing: |click | link=Show Tree... | |
* [info] Executing: |storeAllWindowNames | names | array |
* [info] Executing: |echo | ${names} | |
* [info] echo: ,bdae1e119a367a54
* [info] Executing: |waitForPopUp | ${names} | 30000 |
* [error] Timed out after 30000ms
* [info] Executing: |selectWindow | name=${names} | |
* [error] Window does not exist. If this looks like a Selenium bug, make sure to read http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#alerts-popups-and-multiple-windows for potential workarounds.
```

Where bdae1e119a367a54 is the dynamic value that I want to get.

I found a mach that someone done but it does not works for me it return null

http://old.nabble.com/How-can-I-access-the-second,-third..-element-of-a-stored-array--td9393201.html

Answer (score 0):

Whether the feature works may depend on which browser you are driving.

I would suggest you try a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

```
click              link=Show Tree...
pause              5000
selectWindow       name=${names}
windowFocus
click              link=Search
```

OR

```
storeEval | this.browserbot.findElement('link=Show Tree...').href | myUrl |
open | ${myUrl} ||
```

OR

```
disable the tab feature setting in browser to work with multi-window.
```